# read text file into class object type array ( C++ )

Tags: c++, class

So i have a class object type, myClass classType as a global.
whats not happeing is that would prefer to have

```
// MyClass.h
{
  private:
    char FirstName;
    char LastName;
    char MiddleName;
    int ID;
    int Age;
};

// Globals
const int myIndex = 256;
myClass classType[ myIndex ];

int main()
{

   // assume preprocessors are included

   cout << "Enter File: ";
   cin  >> cArray;
   if ( !inFile.good() ) 
   {
     cout << "Wrong?" << endl;
   }
   inFile.open( cArray );
   while ( !inFile.eof() )
   {
     linecount++ // giving me 1 and not counting the file lines

 inFile.read( ( char * ) &myType[linecount], sizeof( myClass ) );

   }
}
```

Thats a rough idea of what main looks like for me today.
I have yet to use myClass.cpp at all!
My Text file is of this format:

FirstName
LastName
ID Number
Age
...

After debugging, i notice that the newline character was not detected and now everything  is BUNCHED in, on the same index! Like my Increment didnt work or something..

I wanted to increment for however many lines their are in the file. ( more than one )
Im trying to fix the linecount ( idx ) in hopes of fully resolving this issue.

My Private members, FirstName LastName, and so on as i wrote above are present when debugging and dragging on the myclasstype. 
I just Need to get them with their proper varaible.
I just hope the ifstream::read() function is not leading me in a bad direction.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Your names are declared as being only a single character each, which seems incorrect.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code that will prevent it from compiling. You need "struct myClass" in front of the definition of this class; you need to declare cArray, linecount and inFile somewhere; FirstName, LastName and MiddleName are currently a single character each.

Comment: Your problem looks a lot like a homework assignment. You should figure it out by yourself based on the course material you have. This will ensure you actually learn something instead of just passing the assignment with a solution from here.

Answer (score 1):

```
// MyClass.h
{
  private:
    char FirstName;
    char LastName;
    char MiddleName;
    int ID;
    int Age;
};
```

What is this struct/class? I guess that it is myClass. Anyway myClass is not meaningful name.

1. FirstName/LastName/MiddleName eighter are initials - which means that the name is wrong - or are badly typed. What you are looking for is eighter std::string or char *.
2. Traditionally ID is the first field - if it is needed.

``

```
// Globals
const int myIndex = 256;
myClass classType[ myIndex ];
```

As a rule of thumb - never use globals. You **will** have probles.

```
int main()
{

   // assume preprocessors are included

   cout << "Enter File: ";
   cin  >> cArray;
```

What is cArray?

```
   if ( !inFile.good() )
```

Where is inFile defined? Why do you check IO state before any IO operation on this stream?

```
   {
     cout << "Wrong?" << endl;
   }
   inFile.open( cArray );
```

Well. Isn't simpler to write `ifstream inFile(cArray)`?

while ( !inFile.eof() )
   {
     linecount++ // giving me 1 and not counting the file lines

You ask for overflow. What if file have more the 256 lines? What worst program will not crash - it will likely write in some unspecifed place.

```
 inFile.read( ( char * ) &myType[linecount], sizeof( myClass ) );
```

1. Never use binary formats unless you have to. They are very hard to debug. If you have a nice, simple text format all you need to test is a text editor to edit test input files. With binary you have no guarantee that the bug is in the program not in the test case.
2. Evern if you *do* use binary format do **not** read it this way. In fact you have no way to determine if the compiler haven't changed the offsets. For example `ID` will have usually an offset of 4 bytes. But compiler is free to optimize it.

   Additionaly you have no way of determine the size of `ID` and `Age` except they are bigger then 2 bytes. They usually are 4, but on some 64-bits compilers (IMHO such way is correct where `int` == single word) thay may be 8. In the future thay may be 16 (if there will be 128-bit computers). You may think there never be but at the same way "768 K was enought for everybody" (that was a lot those days).

If you try to read text in such way

```
   }
}
```

Unless you need to validate the input (in such case iostreams is not the best tool):

```
class person
{
public:
  person (const std::string &first_name,
          const std::string &last_name,
          const std::string &middle_name,
          int                id,
          int                age)
          : m_first_name(first_name),
            m_last_name(last_name),
            m_middle_name(middle_name,
            m_id(id),
            m_age(age) {}
private:
  std::string m_first_name, m_last_name, m_middle_name;
  int m_id, m_age;
};
// Lots of other code
std::vector<person> people;
while(...)
  {
    std::string first_name, last_name, middle_name;
    int id, age;
    in_file >> first_name >> last_name >> middle_name >> id >> age;
    person p(first_name, last_name, middle_name, id, age);
    people.push_back(p);
  }
```

It can be shorten and it have to be fill but:
 1. Use nice C++ features such as STL (you don't have to remember index or you don't have to worry about vector overflow)
 2. It uses text format

Answer (score 0):

- I've recommended the use of boost::serialization for the same goals.
- Why do you increment linecount before reading a line? You leave the first element of myType uninitialized.
- If you're using a text file format, why are you using the read function?

Answer (score 0):

Several points;

- what is cArray?
- you must test that the file opened using is_open()
- the eof() function will only detect end of file AFTER you have read something
- you should be using std::getline() to read lines
- as was pointed out in a comment, the names in your class are single chars, they should be std::strings

Answer (score 0):

You approach with read(buf, size) won't work if your data comes from a textfile.
It will fill buf with whatever bytes are read from the input.
You can't "fill" an object somewhere in memory that way.
read(buf, size) works only with binary data.

I would overload the stream operator >> to do the actual parsing of the textdata.
The output will be stored in the object passed as a reference:

`istream& operator>> (istream& in, MyClass& val );`